# How to use the QGIS GDAL Toolbox Offset lines?

Tags: qgis, gdal, buffer

I try to create a single sided **Offset line** for a line.
I used the GDAL-Tool "Single sided buffer and offset lines for lines" but I fail.

The error message says "wrong number of arguments to function ST_OffsetCurve()" see the screen shot below.

[image]

What am I doing wrong except that I use QGIS 2.14 under Windows 10 64bit.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There were issues regarding this function which was described in this [forum](https://trac.osgeo.org/postgis/ticket/413) a few years ago which described having to do with optional parameters for the *ST_OffsetCurve()* tool. It is also mentioned [here](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/spatialite-users/25sW07jKC7w) about the difference in parameters used for both the single sided buffer and offset curve.

From my (limited) understanding, it seems that the *Single Side Buffer* function uses the optional [Left Right] parameter to determine if the buffer should be placed on the left or right hand side of the original line. The *Offset Curve* function **does not use this parameter** as the buffer value you give can be negative (left hand side) or positive (right hand side). This is probably why it complains about the number of parameters and outputs an error.

For example, if you select the *Single Side Buffer* operation from the GUI, you should see something like the following in the console:

```
ogr2ogr.exe "\"[temporary file]\"" "C:/Users/Me/Desktop/New folder/line.shp" line -dialect sqlite -sql "SELECT ST_SingleSidedBuffer( geometry , 0.001 ,1),* FROM 'line' "
```

Notice the `,1` value in `ST_SingleSidedBuffer( geometry , 0.001 ,1),*`. This is fine for single side buffer but when using offset curve, this parameter should be removed so that it reads `ST_SingleSidedBuffer( geometry , 0.001),*` instead.

---

I had a go at remedying it by editing the **ogr2ogronesidebuffer.py** script that's saved in:

```
/.qgis2/python/plugins/processing/algs/gdal/
```

You can find the script in the [QGIS Bug Report](https://hub.qgis.org/issues/15342) that was submitted. Copy this script to the `.qgis2` path, restart QGIS and see if it works.

---

Example:

Here's a simple line shapefile:

[image: Line example]

And using a positive buffer value:

[image: Setting parameters]

Result:

[image: Result]

---

I believe the bug has been fixed and will hopefully appear in the upcoming release: https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/commit/1d2b0b4ca7658ed57c4663d9f064ca4bbc55381e

Comment: Perfect solution.

Comment: @EikeMike - Glad it works :)